# Is Python on every GNU/Linux distribution?

Tags: python, linux, desktop, gnu

I would like to know if is Python on every G/L distribution preinstalled or not. And why is it so popular on GNU/Linux and not so much on Windows?

Comment: Programming languages in general are not as common on Windows (at least as far as default installations go).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well python does not come on ALL GNU/Linux distros but is present on most of the popular Linux home user distributions (Ubuntu and Fedora Core for example), possibly because most of the application of Gnome desktop environment and KDE use python 2.5+ (not python 3 yet) interpreters. Since python is almost integrated onto the system/environment from the start, linux users feel easy to program in python. But this is a subjective opinion, as java is still equally popular, if not more, on linux distributions.

Similarly, windows (vista/7) comes prepacked with .net framework, with awesome support for C#, and on Mac OSX objective-C is dominant for most os integrated apps; users just tend to program in languages they deem more "native" to the development environment they are using/targeting.

Comment: cmon, c# isn't even supported in windows xp.  if you are using .NET 3, then you will have to have SP2 or greater on XP

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/267524/do-these-windows-installation-come-with-net-and-if-so-which-versions/267529#267529  this is teh real answer

Answer (score -1):

No, Python is not pre-installed neither installed on every Linux distro.

Comment: In all relevant distros? _Probably, yes_.