# traceback while using subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

```
import sys
import subprocess
arg1= sys.argv[1]
subprocess.call("inversion_remover.py",arg1)
subprocess.call("test3.py")
subprocess.call("test4.py")
```

I am getting the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parent.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.call("inversion_remover.py",arg1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 659, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

How do I solve the above traceback?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in the command as a *list*:

```
subprocess.call(["inversion_remover.py", arg1])
subprocess.call(["test3.py"])
subprocess.call(["test4.py"])
```

otherwise your `arg1` value is passed on to the underlying `Popen()` object as the `bufsize` argument.

Note that the scripts must be found on the *path*. If you want to execute these files from the *local directory* either prefix the path with `./`, or extend the `PATH` environment variable to include the current working directory:

```
subprocess.call(["./inversion_remover.py", arg1])
subprocess.call(["./test3.py"])
subprocess.call(["./test4.py"])
```

or

```
import os

env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join(['.', env['PATH']])

subprocess.call(["inversion_remover.py", arg1], env=env)
subprocess.call(["test3.py"], env=env)
subprocess.call(["test4.py"], env=env)
```

Comment: i am still getting a traceback                                                                   File "./parent.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["inversion_remover.py",arg1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @shubham: and what would that traceback be?

Comment: @shubham: so you don't have an executable `inversion_remover.py` in the path. Try using the full path? Are you sure the script is executable?

Comment: yup its present in that directory

Comment: how do I check whether a script  is executble or not??

Comment: @shubham: is this Windows or a POSIX-compatible OS (Linux, Mac), or something else? Your traceback suggests a POSIX system. Is the executable bit set? `chmod +x filename` will set it. Is there a `#!...` shebang line at the top?

Comment: @shubham: see [What do I use on linux to make a python program executable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/304883)

Comment: i made all the files executible .still getting the traceback

Comment: @shubham: what does `print os.getcwd()` tell you is your current working directory?

Comment: So, when navigating to that folder, `./inversion_remover.py` works? Does using the *full path* (instead of `./`) work?