# Why shebang `env <executable>` instead of `executable`, even when there is no need to pre-set environment variables?

Tags: shell, executable, shebang

Why it is recommended to use /usr/bin/env python as opposed to /usr/bin/python.
This was inspired from reading the responses here:
[What do I use on linux to make a python program executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304883/what-do-i-use-on-linux-to-make-a-python-program-executable/)

I think both would do exactly the same thing, but the answer that mentions both equally has 2 votes, rather than 88 votes for the answer that says to use `env`. People seem to really agree with using env, but don't explain why. Does env help you find any executable named "python", rather than just the one in a specific path which the user could have customized?

I'm really interested to know the various advantages and use cases for using env, and `man env` didn't explain it.  `man env` only says that you can use env to set environment variables before running, NAME=VALUE, but we aren't doing that in the linked example.

I feel the community clearly is recommending to use env, but my own research has not hinted at a reason, so if you have ideas why it's good or good style to do so, please answer.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `#!/usr/bin/env python` ensures that the first Python interpreter in the currently-defined PATH is used, honoring any user overrides (which, for Python, includes `virtualenv`s and the like).

This is particularly important for environments such as MacOS, where OS-vendor packages are often out-of-date (for instance, `/bin/bash` is 3.2 -- a release series from 2006 -- whereas if the user has MacPorts or Homebrew, `/opt/local/bin/bash` or `/usr/local/bin/bash` may be a modern 4.x; thus, `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will gain the benefit of any updated bash interpreter a user has installed, whether system-wide or under their home directory, so long as the location of that interpreter is present in their PATH at runtime).

Comment: Not just versions, but sometimes even existence.  If the script hardcodes `#!/usr/bin/python` but the system has installed `/bin/python`, all the scripts will fail.