# Non readable/editable file format for script files in Linux

Tags: python, file-conversion

I have written a script in a linux machine using python.
 Is there a way to convert .py script file into non readable format such as .exe in windows. 
Let me know your answers please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I use on linux to make a python program executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304883/what-do-i-use-on-linux-to-make-a-python-program-executable)

Answer (score 0):

visit [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) which provides you the tools to create such file.