# Is there a software that can make python scripts (.py files) on ubuntu 18.04 system execute like exe files on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

Is there a software that can make python scripts (.py files) on ubuntu 18.04 system execute like exe files on windows? Double click on ubuntu 18.04 and it will run

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I use on linux to make a python program executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304883/what-do-i-use-on-linux-to-make-a-python-program-executable)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line at the top of the script:
`#!/usr/bin/env python`
And making the script executable with chmod e.g: `chmod 755 script.py` on your command line should do the trick.

You could also use a program like [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/%22) to bundle the script into a linux executable.