# How do I make a single executable combining Python and pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a game on Python, but other people can't play it since they do not have PyGame. I would like to do a package with Python and PyGame in it. How can I do it?

Comment: It'd be actually the best solution to require the users to install Pygame. You don't have to supply every requirement for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second what user286058 says, but if you are on a different OS, there are other options.

### Mac OS X

[py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app) or [platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

### Windows

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org).

### Linux

Probably a little bit more complicated. I have never done this before, but you can get more info 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193077/standalone-python-applications-in-linux)

Or, you can just put all external libraries in a folder and zip or rar them. This is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently packing our Python application (not based on pygame, but with various dependencies) using:

- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) for Linux and Windows
- [Py2pp](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/index.html) for Mac

Once you get to build the first running packages, it's ok, but at first it was a bit tedious to make sure all the resources are correctly gathered and configured.