# How do I make a linux app out of the code using modules installed in a venv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a python code that uses modules installed in a virtual environment. The modules are absent outside the venv. How do I make a Linux app out of the code?
Do I have to install all those packages outside too?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "make a linux app". The standard solution is to have a `setup.py` which tells the user what additional packages they need to install (in a venv if they like). If you want a completely standalone package with all dependencies installed already, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193077/standalone-python-applications-in-linux

Comment: Wrap the Python script call inside a shell script where you first  `source /path/to/your/venv/app/bin/activate`.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Linux applications it all depends on your approach.

If you want to make self-contained apps that will run in any distribution but will also bundle all their dependencies (making the download size bigger), you'll use [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) or [AppImage](https://appimage.org/).

If you're willing to put up with a little bit more effort, you could make a package for each distro-family you want to support (e.g. [Debian (.deb)](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging), [Ubuntu (.snap)](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/), [Fedora (.rpm)](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines), [Arch (.pkg.tar.xz)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/creating_packages)), in that case you'll likely just write your package so it depends on the versions of the libraries you use available in the respective package manager of the distro (if you do that these dependencies will be automatically installed when someone installs your package).

If you want to distribute your application as a Python-based installable, you'll likely write a setup.py containing all instructions required for your application to work (e.g. install dependencies from "pip", move your program to /opt, create a .desktop shortcut in /usr/share/applications).